# Spring Boot Data JPA default schema for stored procedure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, database-schema

I am using Spring boot version 2.1.3. I am calling oracle stored procedure using below code

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name="procName",
        procedureName="proc_name", parameters={
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode="ParameterMode.IN", name="input1", type=String.class),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode="ParameterMode.IN", name="input2", type=String.class),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode="ParameterMode.OUT", name="output`", type=String.class),

    }
        
)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {
...
}
```

Currently I have not provided schema name in procedureName attribute and it gives me error
**PLS-00201 : identifier proc_name must be declared.**

If I provide schema_name above in procedureName attribute like  procedureName="TESTSCHEMA.proc_name"  it works but I need JPA to take schema name from properties file property default_schema like it takes for table
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=TESTSCHEMA

Kindly provide way to take schema from properties file spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema as we want to keep it dynamic and read it from properties file